# Rendering IMAGES (attached to announcement list) in my custom web part?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, asp.net, visual-web-part

Please bear with me as I am brand new to the whole sharepoint world.
I want to be able to display images that have been attached to OOTB announcement list in a custom visual web part I am trying to build. 
I would also like to be able to show the title (from the list) right under the image as a hyperlink (I am thinking I would have to convert it after retrieving it from the list)
I want to display three images in a row with some spacing in between them. 
Here is the code I have as of now:

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://sharepointdev:2000/"))
        {

            using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
            {
                oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                // Fetch the List
                SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists["Announcements"];

                SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
               spQuery.Query = "<Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> <Value Type='Text'></Value> </Eq> </Where>";
                spQuery.Query = "";
                spQuery.RowLimit = 3;

                // Show item in text box
                SPListItemCollection oListCollection = list.GetItems(spQuery);
                foreach (SPListItem item in oListCollection)
                {

                    ListBox1.Items.Add(item.Title);

                }


            }
```

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer, but a thought on an alternative solution. You might want to look into using the content query webpart for something like this, as it will let you grab list items and render them along with an image. You need to have publishing enabled to use that webpart though.

Comment: Andrew thanks for the suggestion but I am trying to work it out with a repeater control in my custom visual web part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a number of small remarks:

- Usually you don't hardcode the URL of the site you want to work against. It may be ok but if you want to access the current site the just use SPContext.Current.Web
- Unless you need to make updates on a get you shouldn't set AllowUnsafeUpdates
- A listbox will not allow you to add images inside it (so in my code I just added a table with links)

To get the full url of attachment you use item.Attachment.UrlPrefix and then add the filename of each attachment. So a sample might be like this:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();
    SPWeb oSPWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

    // Fetch the List  
    SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists["Announcements"];

    SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
    spQuery.Query = "<Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> <Value Type='Text'></Value> </Eq> </Where>";
    spQuery.Query = "";
    spQuery.RowLimit = 3;

    // Show item in text box  
    SPListItemCollection oListCollection = list.GetItems(spQuery);

    var editformUrl = list.Forms[PAGETYPE.PAGE_EDITFORM].ServerRelativeUrl;
    var table = new Table();
    Controls.Add(table);
    table.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    foreach (SPListItem item in oListCollection)
    {
        var fullEditUrl = String.Format("{0}?ID={1}&source={2}",
            editformUrl,
            item.ID,
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString));

        var row = new TableRow();
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        row.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("window.location='{0}';", fullEditUrl);
        row.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Cursor] = "Pointer";

        var titleCell = new TableCell();
        row.Cells.Add(titleCell);
        titleCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("<a href='{1}'><span style='color:lime;'>{0}</span></a>", item.Title, fullEditUrl)));

        var imageCell = new TableCell();
        row.Cells.Add(imageCell);
        if (item.Attachments.Count > 0)
        {
            imageCell.Controls.Add(new HyperLink()
            {
                ImageUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(item.Attachments.UrlPrefix, item.Attachments[0]),
                NavigateUrl = fullEditUrl
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Per Jakobsen Thanks for the valuable info! Additionally, is it possible for me to make/convert them both (Image attachment and Title) into hyperlinks so when a user clicks on either, he would be directed to the edit window with all details shown. I am assuming I would also have to create a image cropping function.

Comment: I was also wondering if I could go ahead and add navigation so the user will be able to navigate left/righ. The latest "three" (which is what I have set my row limit to) would be shown first and then the user could click to the right to see earlier announcements.

Comment: I've added links to EditForm in my sample. Image cropping is a bit outside SharePoint scope look for standard ASP.NET functionality, which might want to use in an EventReceiver. Paging isn't easy using CAML queries lookup SPListItemCollectionPosition on MSDN, but notice that SharePoint only supports forward paging (unless you use the REST interface)

Comment: Hey Per Jakobson  Sorry to bother you again but Im wondering how I might be able to position each of these (Title + Image) side by side and not stacked?

Comment: The easy solution would be to create a table with two columns

Comment: Per Jakobsen I am still trying to understand all the keywords/properties you have used in the code. most of them I get. But I am little confused as to where exactly I would want put the table and rows and if and how I could apply any style to the "Title" text of the Announcements. I am assuming it would be an inline style of <td>? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: The best thing would be to get someone to figure out how the HTML should end up and then just use my code to figure out how to insert the dynamic parts from SharePoint

Comment: The only requirement I have is to be able to display the "Title" text in bold and in a different color and instead of them being stacked up show them side by side

Comment: Per Jakobsen Please take a look at what I have been able to render using your code. Where would I put the table row <tr> and <td> tags to make them appear horizontally as opposed to vertically as shown in the screenshot. The only other styling I would need would be to Change the font-family and color of the Announcement 1, Announcement 2,...... I am assuming this would be a inline style. Please advise. Thanks again

Comment: I've change my example to create a table with Lime text and the entire row as a link (if javascript is on, but does anyone turn it off anymore)